# Can anyone recommend some good podcasts on user experience design?

Tags: learning

I'm at the early stages of learning about this field, and it would be great to listen to some good podcasts on the subject.

Ideally I want to listen to some UX experts getting deep into their subject, even if it's difficult to understand at first, because at least I can get a feel for the kind of issues that come up in UX design.

Any suggestions?

(My own first vote is the 37 Signals podcast, as they seem to cover UX issues a lot. :)

Comment: Post the 37signals podcast as an answer so we can see if other people like it too!

Answer (score 3):

I recommend [the User Experience Podcast](http://www.infodesign.com.au/uxpod) by Gerry Gaffney.

Comment: +1. I like Gerry's broad approach to UX. I particularly liked the interview with anthropologist Genevieve Bell: http://www.infodesign.com.au/uxpod/inteloutside

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend **Jared Spool's Brainsparks podcast**:
http://www.uie.com/brainsparks/topics/podcasts/

Comment: For me lately there were too many follow-up session after a virtual seminar, actual interviews felt rare. Also when there is an event up, they advertise it heavily, which sometimes can be annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Take a listen to Boxes and Arrows too: http://www.boxesandarrows.com/story/index/date/1444

Answer (score 0):

JohnnyHolland.org has a lot of great podcasts from a variety of UX practitioners, speakers at conferences, etc. Talks range from education and design to design practices and methods. A lot of nice perspectives.

JohnnyRadio: http://johnnyholland.org/category/radio-johnny/

Answer (score 0):

I've been listening to The Big Web show, on the 5by5 network. This show is specific to web design, but they have a wide range of guests, and it's always interesting. To give it a try, listen to their interview with Dana Chisnell.

> Dana Chisnell joins Jeffrey Zeldman
>   and Dan Benjamin to talk about UX,
>   testing, leveraging your expertise,
>   New York City voting booth user
>   experience design, and more.

[EPISODE #33: DANA CHISNELL](http://5by5.tv/bigwebshow/33)

Answer (score 0):

I have an Android phone and I use the Google Reader app. In that one I just search for "interaction design" and I get plenty of podcasts!

Answer (score 0):

While not a podcast, Adaptive Path shares a lot of videos from their conferences like UX Week, with great speakers like Jesse James Garret, Peter Merholz, Brandon Schauer...

http://vimeo.com/adaptivepath/videos